# Are the compact three-dimensional submanifolds $\mathbb{R}^3$ unions of cubes of the unit Cartesian lattice?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology, submanifold, triangulation

Is it true that the following two classes of subsets $\mathbb{R} ^ 3$ coincide:

1. $\{f (D_ε (A)) \,\mid\, f \, \text{is an ambient isotopy, A is the union of a finite collection of closed cubes of the unit Cartesian lattice}\}$
2. Compact three-dimensional submanifolds

where $D_r (A) = \bigcup\limits_{a \in A} \{x \, \mid \, d(x, a) \leq r\}$ is a closed $r$-neighborhood of the set, and $ε = \frac{1}{100}$. In other words, before union, each closed cube is increased by $\frac{1}{100}$ in all directions (thus eliminating special points of contact of the cubes along the top).

The inclusion of 1 in 2 is obvious.

P.S. It is known that all 3-manifolds are triangulable; therefore, it is not excluded that the inclusion of 2 in 1 is also true.

Comment: Yes, you do not even need to take the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods. But the proof that I know is quite tedious.

Comment: Two cubes with one common vertex are not a three-dimensional manifold (when this vertex is dropped, the space becomes disconnected). D_r must be used.

Thank you comment! Maybe you can recommend books?

Comment: Of course, but nobody forces you to consider such unions:

Comment: Yeah, of these two ways to achieve the coincidence of the first class of sets with the second - I chose neighborhoods :)